# How to for loop iterate for two variables?

Tags: c, for-loop

I want to know how for loop is processed in below condition.

```
void main()
{  
    int i,j;
    For(i=1,j=1;i<=5,j<=10,i++,j++)
    {
        printf("%d%d",i,j);
    }
}
```

sorry for typo mistake I correct my syntax here

For(i=1,j=1;i<=5,j<=10;i++,j++)

answer of this -1122334455667788991010

How's that possible because loop for I will be iterate for only 5 times how's that possible ?
I want to know how loop will be executed ?

Comment: Could you make your question more clear?

Comment: This wouldn't compile. Should the third comma be a semicolon?

Answer (score 4):

This won't compile, there's only one `;` in the `for` which is a syntax error.

I'll assume it should read like this:

```
for(i=1, j=1; i<=5, j<=10; i++, j++)
```

*then* it would step both `i` and `j` to 10.

This is because the `for`-loop's middle part, the condition, reads `i<=5,j<=10` which is a use of the comma operator where perhaps a boolean and (`&&`) would be better.

It will evaluate `i<=5`, throw away that result, and then evaluate `j<=10`, running the loop for as long as that value is non-zero.

Comment: "`true`" would probably be clearer than "non-zero" here.

Comment: @Quentin I don't think so, since the type of the result is `int` and people expect `true` to be of type `_Bool` (or `bool`).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** args){
    for(int i = 0, j=0; i<10&&j<10; i++, j++){
        printf("%d, %d\n", i, j);
    }
}
```

The semi colon's seperate the terms of the for statement. (`intializer; condition; action at end of loop`) You can do what you like for the sections.

Comment: When they posted this, their problem appeared to be a `,` and they didn't ask why how. I just pasted the correct syntax.